# Make slideshow at certain interval for kwick

Tags: jquery, html, slider, kwicks

I have a kwick slider.The imagesmoves only if i click on the left or right arrows.Can i make them change at certain interval like a slide show?

```
<div class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
        <li> <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/203531_185817528257_850962705_q.jpg" alt="" > </li>
        <li> <img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/t5/276179_100005675229344_1403962148_q.jpg" alt="" > </li>
        <li> <img src="http://devsmash.com/img/powered-by-nodejitsu.png" alt="" > </li>
        <li> <img src="https://fbcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/1426584_613258465390797_1132303038_a.jpg" alt="" > </li>
        <li> <img src="https://fbcdn-creative-a.akamaihd.net/hads-ak-prn1/t45/s110x80/735332_6007868282382_1944105814_n.png" alt="" > </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
```

this is the html. I have set up a fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/cbB5P/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all sort of options. Check the docs or code. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/cbB5P/1/

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
       slideshow: true,
       slideshowSpeed: 2000,
       animationSpeed: 400
})
```

Check more options here: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L1047